# how to display image from image_url from my db in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to upload a profile picture of the user those who are registering. I had uploaded and stored the url of that profile picture in my DB. Now, I need to show that image from that image url. I had done the below code. But it's not working. `echo 'echo '<img src= "<?php echo $location; ?>">';`

```
$up=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile']'tmp_name'],dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_‌​ROOT']).'/htdocs/upload/image/'.$name);
$path = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/htdocs/upload/image/';     
$location = $path . $_FILES['profile']['name'];
$ins=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into image (url) values ('$location')"); echo '<img src= "'.$location.'"/>'
```

$location is the variable where i saved the image url.

Comment: If it is PHP file, then `echo "<img src= '$location'>";` will do

Comment: dont forget to add ALT text and width ./ height dimensions and possible even a title (all of which can be stored in the db and pulled into the page when you bring in the image.

Comment: I had done the code echo '<img src= "'.$location.'"/>';  but it's not working. Please help with some code.

Comment: post your code then we help be more descriptive:)

Comment: $up=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile']'tmp_name'],dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/htdocs/upload/image/'.$name);      $path = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/htdocs/ upload/image/'; 
$location = $path . $_FILES['profile']['name'];
$ins=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into image (url) values('$location')");
echo '<img src= "'.$location.'"/>';

Comment: @Jebil, Instead of posting this code in comment, you should edit your question and paste there....

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<img src= "'.$location.'"/>';
```

Comment: Ya i had done the code echo '<img src= "'.$location.'"/>';  but it's not displaying nothing

Comment: When i echo $location, it displays the url which is stored in db.

Comment: copy this url and run it in your browser to verify that file exists there or not ?? @Jebil

Comment: Ya i verified. It displays the image when i copy the url and view it in another tab.

Comment: Then you need to inspect your HTML and look img tag  and src of this image tag.

Comment: I inspect my page. The miracle is, it passed the image tag with the url of the image. But the image is not displaying in my web page.

Comment: Now i set the width and height for my img tag. But it displays the border of the given width and height. But there is no image.

Comment: Now i restart my browser and restart my xampp server. But the same result, not displaying the image.

Comment: you have an extra space in your path `$path = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/htdocs/upload/image/';` replace this line ...

Comment: When i add the code, i just entered the space, but in my real coding there is no space.

Comment: [Visit this link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000813.htm) check your browser settings..

Comment: Show all images is selected in my browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<img src='$location'>";`

Comment: I done the correction. When i echo $location, it displays the url which is stored in db and i verified. It displays the image when i copy the url and view it in another tab. Please help.